# RND Query working in Access but not in ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a simple rnd query that works fine in Access but when I run it on my asp page I get the exact same record everytime. I'm updated my original post to show new SQL in asp page and my DB connection.

Access:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblPlayers.*
FROM tblPlayers
WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like "*aaa*"))
ORDER BY Rnd([LID]);
```

ASP Page (based on feedback from comments below)

```
Dim sql, rssql

sql = "SELECT TOP 1 tblPlayers.* "
sql=sql & "FROM tblPlayers "
sql=sql & "WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like '%aaa%')) "
sql=sql & "ORDER BY Rnd([LID]); "

set rssql = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")
rssql.Open sql, conn
```

DB Connection

```
<%
Dim conn 
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
conn.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("/_db/database.mdb") & ""
%>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: To replicate your working query exactly wouldn't you need to do: `sql=sql & "WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like ""*aaa*"")) "` OR `sql=sql & "WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like '*aaa*')) "`? Why are you swapping out the asterisks? I'm not sure percentage symbols are valid wildcard markers in Access.

Comment: Please add the entire relevant code, including the lines which execute SQL command and establish a connection in ASP.

Comment: @Adam if they are still using Access as the database then you are absolutely right, it should be `""*aaa*""` not `'%aaa%'` as that is SQL Server T-SQL query syntax.

Comment: When adding my code do I use comment, edit (original) or answer my question? Thanks

Comment: @ryzerman You should [edit] to add to your existing post.

Comment: Problems with RND usually stem from either not seeding the generator before using (get the same numbers every run) or RND returning float 0-1 instead of a range of integers.

Comment: I'm coming to this problem again. I tried all suggestions have unfortunately none have worked. I came across a 2009 posting for ASP.NET. The problem was actually my issue.  https://forums.asp.net/t/1158634.aspx#1910539 

This was the solution but I have no idea why it appears to work. 

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tblPlayers WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like '%aaa%')) ORDER BY Rnd(-10000000*TimeValue(Now())*[LID])"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 1 tblPlayers.* "
sql=sql & "FROM tblPlayers "
sql=sql & "WHERE (((tblPlayers.FN) Like '%aaa%')) "
sql=sql & "ORDER BY NewId(); "
```

https://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm